# The jwt service this.jwtService.sign is not a function

Tags: typescript, jwt, nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

With this code in AuthService:

```typescript
@Injectable()
AuthService {

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
    private jwtService: JwtService
    private userRepository: UserRepository
    ) {
  }

  async login(loginCredentialsDto: LoginCredentialsDto): Promise<{ accessToken: string }> {
    const email = await this.userRepository.validatePassword(loginCredentialsDto);
    const payload: JwtPayLoad = {email};
    return {
        accessToken: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
    };
  }
}
```

Once it is compiled during runtime I get the following error:

> [Nest] 12998   - 07/03/2020, 9:22:20 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] this.jwtService.sign is not a function +213303ms

Following is the AuthModule:

```typescript
@Module({
    imports: [
        PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
        JwtModule.register({
            secret: 'topSecret51',
            signOptions: {
                expiresIn: 3600,
            }
        }),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository])],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
    exports: [
        JwtStrategy,
        PassportModule,
    ], }) 
export class AuthModule { }
```

Any ideas how this can be resolved?

I have re-installed npm, removed node modules and tried to modify code. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was in the Authservice constructor should be like:

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
    private userRepository: UserRepository,
    private jwtService: JwtService) {
}
```